# how to unit test navigator.notification.alert

Tags: javascript, qunit

I'm trying to unit test a javascript function and am unable to fake navigator.notification.alert. Does anyone have any ideas?  Here's the code that I've tried:

```
navigator = {  
      notification = {  
          alert: function( textStatus, null, title, button ) {  
               alert("Success!);  
      }  
   }  
};
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You have an unclosed string literal.  Surely that wasn't intentional?

Comment: Sorry, no that wasn't intentional.  Typing too fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to *mock* the getter (i.e. define a custom one). This should work in most browsers:

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('notification', function () {
    return {
        alert: function () {
            document.write("Success!");
        }
    }
});
```

[See the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/L2Jce/) to try it yourself.